# Poor quality suspended ceiling installation

Tags: basement-refinishing

My home has a poorly installed suspended ceiling in my basement using 2'x 4' tiles with many tiles sagging and not attractive. I am not a fan of suspended ceilings. Is there a better ceiling choice that I should consider instead? Or should I invest in replacement tiles to improve the appearance? Many of the tiles sag or are discolored. I suspect they were probably installed in the mid' 70's.

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement! Unfortunately, any answer to this question will be a matter of opinion. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.

Comment: Some pictures would make a lot of difference for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are several alternate ceilings that could be installed: 1) suspended ceiling with decorative panels, 2) gypsum board on suspended metal runners, 3) gypsum board applied directly to floor supports,

First, if the existing tiles have water stains (which turn brown) and sag, it could be due to a leak. You’ll need to find and fix the leak before installing a new ceiling.

1) There are many decorative suspended ceiling options. Here’s some options:  https://www.decorativeceilingtiles.net/suspended-drop-ceiling-tiles/

Or:  https://www.proceilingtiles.com/

2) Because your existing ceiling is suspended and you like a standard gypsum board ceiling (to match the rest of your house), you may need to suspended it on metal runners. Like this:
http://web.nwcb.org/CWT/External/WCPages/WCWebContent/WebContentPage.aspx?ContentID=98

3) The most common (and probably cheapest) is gypsum board applied directly to the bottom of the floor supports. However, if you have heating ducts, electrical wiring, etc. under the floor supports, then moving all that will be expensive.

Comment: Aren't there new types of panels for suspended ceilings which are stiffer and lighter weight? Replacing the panels would be by far the easiest and cheapest solution.